# ¿Por qué "pardillo" es "rústico, ignorante, incauto"?

Tags: etimología, historia, dle

En el DLE figura [**pardillo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RuLLPt4) como

> Del dim. de *pardo*.
>   1. adj. despect. Dicho de una persona: **Rústica o ignorante**. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. despect. Dicho de una persona: **Incauta, que se deja estafar fácilmente**. U. t. c. s.

Sin embargo, ninguna de las acepciones de [**pardo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RuQF03b) parece tener ninguna relación:

> Del lat. *pardus* 'leopardo', por alus. a su color, y este del gr. πάρδος *párdos*.
>   1. adj. Dicho de un color: Semejante al de la tierra o al de la piel del oso, y que tira a marrón o a rojizo. U. t. c. s. m.
>   2. adj. De color pardo.
>   3. adj. Dicho especialmente de las nubes o del día nublado: oscuro (‖ sin luz o claridad).
>   4. adj. Dicho de la voz: Que no tiene timbre claro y que es poco vibrante.
>   5. adj. *Ant., Arg., Ec., Hond., Méx., Perú, Ur. y Ven.* p. us. mulato (‖ nacido de negro y blanca, o de blanco y negra). U. m. c. s.
>   6. m. leopardo.

¿Cómo adquirió **pardillo**, diminutivo de **pardo**, esas acepciones tan diferentes a las de la palabra original?

Comment: Supongo que es por el racismo, simple y sencillamente.

Comment: In Brazil, it's not racist. :) Anyway, slaves were often in the country (as opposed to the city).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece bastante lógico que se deba a que, hasta hace bien poco, los campesinos (rústicos, rurales) tenían la piel oscura por su exposición al Sol. Eran los ricos los que hacían alarde de ser blancos, incluso las reinas usaban polvos de arroz para blanquearse la piel. El ser moreno de piel denotaba exposición al Sol, asociada al trabajo en el campo. "Los ricos son refinados y no se manchan las manos".

Answer (score 4):

Una posible explicación es que derivara de la acepción que **pardillo** tenía en el Diccionario de Autoridades (1737):

> adj. que se aplica à el paño mas tosco, grosséro y basto, que se hace del color pardo y sin tinte, de que viste la gente humilde y pobre: y asi se suele decir, Gente del pardillo.

Answer (score 0):

Si, viene de dejarse engañar. Hay un pajarito llamado "pardillo", así cabe pensar que lo más lógico es que el ave era una presa fácil de capturar, ya sea imitando su gorjeo o alimentándolo con algo liviano como forma de atraerlo.